# Pdf layers to Geodatabase

Tags: esri-geodatabase, pdf

We had a drawing as a PDF , with Geolocation and layer information available. We tried to export that as an Xml ( current tree) option in Adode reader and tried to import it in a new File geodatabase.

The error we encountered was there is no workspace associated with the Xml.

What would be the ideal procedure to convert a Pdf to a Geodatabase ?

Comment: I notice that this has also been posted to the [**ArcGIS Discussion Forum**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/84997-Export-Xml-from-PDF-and-import-to-Geodatabase?p=299970#post299970).  Are you trying to extract vector features from a GeoPDF and then load it into a File Geodatabase?  If so, perhaps you can give more details of your steps and software.  A file geodatabase is likely to be very particular about the XML it tries to [**import**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000014s000000).

Comment: It's no wonder you're getting an error.  The XML when exporting from a PDF is not an XML workspace for importing into ArcGIS.

Comment: @ Poly geo - Exactly ! We are trying to extract features and load into File GDB. We are using adobe reader and ArcGIS 10.1 ..As for the steps , pretty straight - we unlock the layer and geolocation information and export layer with current tree option

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/)'s [Geospatial PDF driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pdf.html) (new at version 1.10).

See also the [Geospatial PDF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_PDF) article on Wikipedia for more background information.